# C++ for loop using an array

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, multiplication

I know this is a basic question, but I'm a Python user very new to C++

I need to compute a function `(cosmology.bias_eff)` using a `for` loop for which the input parameter `(Mass_min)` needs to be multiplied by an array `(M_ratio)`.

I am **making a mistake** here by using **two `for` loops**.

```
vector<double> M_ratio = {1.0,0.9,1.1,1.05,1.1,1.15,1.2,1.25,1.2};
double Mass_min = 2e13;
double Delta0 = 200.0;

for (redshift=0.0;redshift<1.7;redshift=redshift+0.2)
{   
    for (size_t i=0; i<M_ratio.size(); i++)
    {
        double Delta = cosmology.DeltaR(Delta0, redshift);

        double bias_eff = cosmology.bias_eff(M_ratio[i]*Mass_min,redshift,Delta);

        cout << bias_eff <<"," << endl;
    }
}
```

**What I want is**, for each `redshift` in the `for` loop, I want `Mass_min` to be multiplied by `M_ratio`,

**i.e. for `redshift = 0.0, Mass_min = Mass_min*1.0`, for `redshift = 0.2, Mass_min = 0.9*Mass_min` and so on.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need only a single loop:

```
vector<double> M_ratio = {1.0,0.9,1.1,1.05,1.1,1.15,1.2,1.25,1.2};
double redshift;
int i;
for (redshift=0.0,i=0; i<M_ratio.size(); i++,redshift+=0.2) {
  double Delta = cosmology.DeltaR(Delta0, redshift);
  double bias_eff = cosmology.bias_eff(M_ratio[i]*Mass_min,redshift,Delta);
  cout << bias_eff <<"," << endl;
}
```

On each iteration, `redshift` in incremented by 0.2, at the same time `i` is incremented by one. Inside the loop the needed computation takes place.

Comment: but shouldn't it be `for (double redshift = 0.0, i=0;)` instead of `int` ?